# In javascript how can I use a variable as part of an object property's name

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Say for example I have an array and it has property but I want to make a few more properties but each one with a different number at the end for example

```
array[0][0].property0 = "";
array[0][0].property1 = "";
array[0][0].property2 = "";
```

but instead of manually naming them I want to use a variable, something like

```
var x = 0
array[0][0].property + x = "";
```

how can I use the variable x in an object property such as this?

Comment: `array[0][0][property + x]` please see duplicate question.

Comment: yes it is. have a look here: [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Sorry I am fighting with the comments right now I will look at that link Thank You